# Joining 2 tables error

Tags: sql, join, left-join, inner-join

I'm trying to join 2 tables to get an output report. The tables involved are the stock and dailysales table.

Stock and Dailysales tables:

[image]

Desired output format:

[image]

I am trying to join 2 tables by using the below query

```
Select item,article,sold,stockonhand
from stock S
left join dailysales as D on S.item=D.item
group by item
```

I want the output to include all rows from the stock table. Like there is stock, but not sold, also to be included in the report. Currently my report is does not show, (stocked but not sold).

Hope you can understand my context or point me to a tutorial which I could read up. I tried to search for few days and couldn't find an exact question to mine.

Comment: What error you are getting and also just make sure to specify in select query that the columns belongs to which table..

Comment: You are using 'Group By' without aggregate function that make any sens

Comment: I tried the solution by Sagi and got 3 rows of results. Item 126 (Guitar) is still not appearing. This item is not sold but it's stocked, so I would like this to appear too.

Comment: I'm able to get the flute to show but it's the Guitar that is not showing, I tried all the joins but not able to get it to show. It will always show me the records from the right table. Left stock table 100 records, right sales table 5 records, but it will always show me 5 records even with left join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sum the item in a separated table, it would be clearer than `GROUP BY` 2 tables

```
SELECT 
    s.item, 
    s.article, 
    ISNULL(ds.sold, 0) AS qtysold, 
    s.stockonhand
FROM 
    stock s OUTER APPLY 
    (SELECT SUM(sold) AS sold FROM dailysales WHERE item = s.item GROUP BY item) ds
```

Answer (score 2):

Not tested -

```
select item,article,sum(sold),sum(stockonhand)-sum(sold) from (
 select a.item,a.article,a.stockonhand,case when b.sold is null then 0 else b.sold end as sold 
 from stock a left join dailysales b on (a.item = b.item))
group by item,article;
```

It's basically does the left join and put 0 on the null column(for sum after)
and then summing up the results grouping by all the columns in the select(that what was wrong with your query)

Answer (score 1):

Simply `LEFT JOIN` the two tables (to get the flute too), do a `GROUP BY`, and `SUM` the sold:

```
select s.item, s.article, coalesce(SUM(d.sold),0) as "qty sold", s.stockonhand
from stock S
left join dailysales as D on S.item=D.item
group by s.item, s.article, s.stockonhand
```

The `coalesce` is there to replace `NULL` with `0`, for items not sold.  (Thanks sagi!)

General `GROUP BY` tip: *If a `GROUP BY` clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.*

Also, you can remove the `article` column from the `dailysales` table. That data is already stored in the `stock` table. Never store same data twice! (Normalization!) Risk for data inconsistency if you keep that column.

Comment: and what will happend with the null column when you sum them?

Comment: NULL's aren't counted.

Comment: But he wants them to appear on the result as 0

Comment: I'm not sure why I am not able to get those item not sold (in this case, GUITAR) to appear. The left join seem to not be working. The result only show those sold.

Comment: I'm able to get the flute to show but it's the Guitar that is not showing, I tried all the joins but not able to get it to show. It will always show me the records from the right table. Left stock table 100 records, right sales table 5 records, but it will always show me 5 records even with left join.

Comment: @louise, Very odd. `LEFT JOIN` is supposed to return every row from the left side table, even without any matches in the right side table. What happens if you skip the `GROUP BY` and `SUM`, just do a `left join` - do you get any guitar rows?